# while saving mongoDB data after refreshing it again saving same data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning mongodb & Mongoose. I built a employee detail records and my code is working. But there is one issue as I refresh page again it submit previous data. How can I solve this error.

```
router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
const empData = req.body;
const postData = new empDetails({
name: empData.name,
age: empData.age,
department: empData.department,
email: empData.email,
present: empData.present,
empType: empData.type,
rate: empData.rate,
hours: empData.hours,
total: parseInt(empData.rate) * parseInt(empData.hours),
});

postData.save(function (err, res1) {
if (err) throw err;
employeeDetails.exec(function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.render("employee", { title: "Employee Details", records: data });
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Whenever you call `save` it will create a
new document. If you want to restrict creation of same document twice or multiple times, you need to check if the document already exists before calling `save`. There are two ways to prevent creation of document with same data:

1. You will have to check for the document with `findOne`. If the document exists don't call `save`, if not insert a new document.
2. Define unique compound index on the fields which are making a unique combination so as not letting to insert the document with same data.

Reference can be taken from here: [Unique Compound Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index)

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. reference given by you helped me a lot.

Comment: Did it help in solving the problem?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you in achieving what you expected.